# How to use if and else condition in robotframework ,If node a as a child it should click the child else it should click node b

Tags: robotframework

How to use if and else condition in robotframework ,If 'A'node as a child it should  click the child node, else it should click node 'B'.

```
xpath=(.//*[@id='functionals-tab-content']/ul/li/ul/li[${to clickplus firstplus}]/ul/li[${child node click value}]/ul/li[${child node click value1}]/div[1]/a)--- child node of A.

xpath=(.//*[@id='functionals-tab-content']/ul/li/ul/li[${to clickplus firstplus}]/ul/li[${child node click value}]/ul/li[${child node click value1}])--- B node.
```

"Run Keyword If Element Should Be Visible   child node of A.  click element child node of A

Run Keyword Unless   Element Should Be Visible    B node.    click element  B node.

If give like this its not exceuting throwing error. how to write if and else condition for this. can anyone help me.

Answer (score 2):

[Run keyword if](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Run%20Keyword%20If) requires a python expression; you can't substitute that with a keyword. You'll have to split your statements into two. First, call your keyword and save the result, and then use the result in the if statement.

```
${result}=    Run keyword and ignore error    Element should be visible    ${node A}
Run keyword if    '${result[0]}' == 'PASS'
...    click element    ${node A}
...    ELSE
...    click element    ${node B}
```

An example using [Run keyword if](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Run%20Keyword%20If) and [Run keyword and ignore error](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Run%20Keyword%20And%20Ignore%20Error) is included in the documentation for the [built-in](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html) library (specifically, in the documentation for [Run Keyword If](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Run%20Keyword%20If))

**Note:** `Run keyword and ignore error` returns a tuple of two values. The first value will be the string `'PASS'` or `'FAIL'`.

**Note:** the use of [continuations](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#dividing-test-data-to-several-rows) (`...`) is not necessary to make the keywords work. Personally I find they make the code considerably easier to read than if you try to put all of that on a single line.

Comment: ${result} = ('PASS', None)
FAIL : Evaluating expression ''('PASS', None)' == 'PASS'' failed: SyntaxError: invalid syntax (<string>, line 1). when i  gave the above code. its generating error.

Comment: @karthikas: I updated my answer. I forgot that `Run keyword and ignore error` returns a tuple.

Comment: Run keyword if    '${result[0]}' == 'PASS'
...    click element    ${node A}
...    ELSE
...    click element    ${node B}                                                                  After this condition how to say if node A is clicked  it should click A[1] or   if node B is clicked it should  click b[1]

Comment: can any one help me. i m stuck how to use condition here   how to say if node A is clicked it should click A[1] or if node B is clicked it should click b[1]